# Why does this 'kill' command log me out of the computer?

Tags: command-line, kill

The following command signs me out (**do not** run this command):

```
kill -9 -1
```

I don't understand why.

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The syntax is `kill SIGNAL PID`.

The `-9` option specifies that the `SIGKILL` signal should be sent (immediately terminate the target process(es), and specifying the PID `-1` is shorthand for "all processes except itself and init".

Since you don't use `sudo` (and presumably don't have root permissions), this immediately kills all processes you have permission to kill - your entire session, hence logging you out.

Comment: And note, if you run this command with sudo like `sudo kill -9 -1` then the computer will restart

Comment: Will it really restart? It seems like it would just crash.

Comment: @user606723 the init process will not exit, and can decide what (if anything) to do about all the other processes having exited.

Comment: @Anwar it will not necessarily restart, it will drop you to running just init, which may or may not then spawn a shell or bring back up other services.

Answer (score 27):

try

```
man kill
```

to get an explanation of the kill command..

it says:

> A PID of -1
>         is special; it indicates all processes except the kill  process  itself
>         and init.

and

> **EXAMPLES**
>
> kill -9 -1
>
> ```
>  Kill all processes you can kill.
> ```

I hope you understand why your computer will log you out, when you end all processes. You quitted everything.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for pointing to `man`. "Teach a fish how to `man` and you feed him for a lifetime." (Pun intended :-))

Answer (score 8):

You are giving `-1` as the process id: from the `kill` man-page:

```
 A  PID of -1 is special; it indicates all processes except the
 kill process itself and init.
```